# Create a hierarchical object from HTML outline

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, recursion

I'm ultimately wanting to create a jQuery plugin that loops through the top level of the DOM and adds elements to an object until it gets to a heading, at which point it pushes an object with the text of that heading.

The following sibling elements would be added to this new object until a new heading is encountered — if the heading is at the same level, a new object is created as a sibling of the parent object as before, and DOM siblings are added to that instead of the first object; if the heading is at a lower level, that's added as a child of the first object, and sibling DOM elements are added as children to that heading object; if it's a higher level headline, a new object is added one level above the last heading object and the cycle continues.

Example:

```
<p>wooo</p>
<h1>stuff</h1>
<p>stuff</p>
<p>more stuff</p>
<h2>yet more stuff</h2>
<p>still more stuff</p>
<h3>even still more stuff</h3>
<p>yep — stuff!</p>
<h1>still yet more stuff</h1>
<p>stuff stuff stuff</p>
<p>stuff stuff stuffarino</p>
```

Becomes...

```
{
  'p_wooo': HTMLElementObject,
  'h1_stuff': {
    'p_stuff': HTMLElementObject,
    'p_more_stuff': HTMLElementObject,
    'h2_yet_more_stuff': {
      'p_still_more_stuff': HTMLElementObject,
      'h3_even_still_more_stuff': {
        'p_yep_stuff': HTMLElementObject,
      }
    },
  },
  'h1_still_yet_more_stuff': {
    'p_stuff_stuff_stuff': HTMLElementObject,
    'p_stuff_stuff_stuffarino': HTMLElementObject
  {
}
```

Here's [what I have so far](https://github.com/times/doctop/blob/master/src/doctop.js#L23):

```
    var root = $(res)
                .filter('#contents')
                .children()
                .not('style'); // Don't need no stylesheets hurr!

    var sections = root.filter('h1');
    var outline = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < sections.length; i++) {
      var children;
      if (i+1 <= sections.length) {
        children = root.filter(sections[i]).after().nextUntil(sections[i+1]).filter(function(){return $(this).text().trim() !== '';});
      }

      var slug = getSlug($(sections[i]).text(), {separator: '_'});
      outline[slug] = children;
   }

   console.dir(outline);
```

Alas, it only works for H1s. **How would I turn this into a recursive function that adds H2-H6s?**

Comment: You can create the object with the keys in any order you like, but you can't *retrieve* an object's keys in the originally-inserted order. If you need ordered collections, use arrays.

Comment: @PaulRoub Is there any way to do named array keys in JavaScript? I know in PHP you can create arrays like `["something" => "hurr", 1 => "derpa"]` and they'll maintain some sort of order, IIRC. Apologies if this is a dumb question, I'm a bit over-caffeinated at the moment.

Comment: No. JS arrays are index by number only. Non-numeric indices are for objects, and are unordered. Period.

Comment: Updated question with example code.

Comment: For those downvoting, please include a comment explaining why. I can't improve my questions if I don't get any feedback. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll start you with an example that traverses the nodes and adds them all into the same `tree` object. It should be fairly easy to figure out the rest from here:

JSBin: http://jsbin.com/bixekutuhe/1/edit?html,js,output

```
// Helpers
function isNode(el) { return el && el.nodeType === 1; }
function tag(el) { return el.tagName.toLowerCase(); }

var tree = {}, key;
var node = document.body.firstElementChild;

while (isNode(node) && tag(node) !== 'script') { // add blacklists or whitelists that you might need
  key = node.textContent;

  tree[node.tagName.toLowerCase() + '_' +key.split(' ').join('_')] = node;
  node = node.nextElementSibling; // move to next element
}

console.log(tree);
```

### Update

Try the following example instead:

```
var tree = {};
var currentTree = tree, tagName, key;
var node = document.body.firstElementChild;

function isNode(el) { return el && el.nodeType === 1; }
function tag(el) { return el.tagName.toLowerCase(); }

while (isNode(node)) {
  tagName = tag(node);
  key = tagName + '_' + node.textContent.trim().split(' ').join('_');

  switch(tagName) {
    case 'h1':
    case 'h2':
    case 'h3':
    case 'h4':
    case 'h5':
    case 'h6':
      if (tagName === 'h1') {
        currentTree = tree[key] = {};
      } else {
        currentTree = currentTree[key] = {};
      }
    break;

    default:
      currentTree[key] = node;
    break;
  }

  // Move to the next element
  node = node.nextElementSibling;
}

console.log(tree);
```

Comment: The issue I'm having isn't really adding top-level elements to the top-level of a tree...

Comment: See if the new example helps.